# How to correctly return all items in a laravel collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Currently trying to display a list of all objects in a collection `subfleets`
I am using the `get` command but only returns the first object:

```
<tr>
    <td>@lang('flights.subfleets')</td>
    <td>{{ $flight->subfleets->get(0)->name }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#loops

```
@foreach($flight->subfleets as $subFleet)
   <tr>
      <td>{{ $subFleet->name }}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate $flight->subfleets->get() using @foreach;

```
@foreach($flight->subfleets->get() as $subFleet)
   <tr>
      <td>{{ $subFleet->name }}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I get an error : Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed

Comment: Try `$flight->subfleets()->get()` or `$flight->subfleets`